# Best practice to dependency resolve in Jboss EAP

Tags: jboss

In case of war file deployment, there are two possible ways to resolve dependency in Jboss EAP:

1. we could keep all the dependent jar files in Jboss modules and get access of them using jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.
2. we could keep all the jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder inside war file.

Which one is the best practice to follow and why?

Comment: If possible, I'm using option #2. Because modules loaded with different classloader and that cause problem with some libs. Also with #2 you can update your wars without stopping wildfly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you prefer.

**#1** means you need to configure server and application(s), and this is more effective when you have more applications on server using these modules as dependencies. So you save space from duplicating libraries in more applications.

**#2** means you have almost all dependencies in your deployment application => bigger file/directory (but don't forget some dependencies are automatically enabled by container based on what you use Servlets, JPA etc.).